# HTML5 and CSS Inline Unordered Lists in IE 8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I'm still a bit new to CSS in general, so be gentle. I am trying to create a basic unordered, horizontal list that lists divs (they will later be given a background image since this will be used as a navigation bar). For some reason, I cannot seem to get it to display. I am testing against IE8 since I figure if it works in that browser, it works in them all (I will test in other browsers as I get closer to finishing, I promise).

I am using `<!DOCTYPE html>`

### The CSS

```
#nav_list {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
margin:auto;}

.list{display:inline;}

.nav_option {margin:auto; border:solid black 1px; width:50px;}
```

### The HTML

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="nav_list">
    <li class="list Home"><div class="nav_option Home">Home </div></li>
    <li class="list Shop"><div class="nav_option Shop"> Shop</div></li>
    <li class="list Game"><div class="nav_option Game">Game </div></li>
    <li class="list Map"><div class="nav_option Map">Map</div></li>
    <li class="list Information"><div class="nav_option Information">Information</div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

For some reason, I cannot even get IE to put borders around it nonetheless get it inline. What am I messing up?

Comment: While you're using a HTML5 DOCTYPE, this question really has nothing to do with HTML5.

Comment: True, but that's probably because he's new to CSS 'and' HTML in general, which is totally normal.

Comment: Inline elements do not have a height or width so there is nothing to put the border around. I suggest you get a beginning html/css book or go through an online css navigation tutorial as you are doing some wonky stuff that is going to cause problems in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to float your div.

```
.nav_option {margin:auto; border:solid black 1px; width:50px; float:left}
```

Comment: Ed: If I float it left, will that prevent me from centering the aligned list? Is there a way that I could put it inside another div that was centered with margin:auto and left align it to that specific div while forcing the width as close as possible?

Answer (score 0):

@Signify, what I would do is float the li elements, or "list", instead of displaying "inline". Or maybe float the .nav_option as Ed Charbeneau said. 
Also, since you're starting, do you understand that when you set class="list Home" you're actually setting two classes to that li item? Same thing when you use class="nav_option Home". To use both classes, in your CSS to use both classes you would use something like:

li.list.Home

This can be useful sometimes but, again, since you're starting, I doubt you need both. Same thing for your divs inside each list item.

So, I believe you could simplify things and use something like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="home">Home</li>
        <li class="shop">Shop</li>
        <li class="game">Game</li>
        <li class="map">Map</li>
        <li class="info">Information</li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

And only add more tags and classes if you really need them. Note that I'm using the  tag, an HTML5 tag.
With that in place there are already loads of things you can do. Depending on your layout and how much you care about old browsers, sometimes you don't even need all those classes. You can "point to" each one of them in your css by using li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2), etc... well, there are much much more options... all depends of what you want to achieve.

And one last time: I really doubt you need all those classes (and even elements).

Comment: When I tried floating it, even though I had list-style-type:none; the bullets still showed up and overlapped the elements. Any idea why that happens?

Comment: Yep, I know what's happening Signify. The property you're using is wrong, and the element too. What you should be using to get rid of the bullets is this: ul { list-style: none; } Note that I'm using the list-style: none; on the ul element.

Answer (score 0):

7th is right. You might want to think if you really need all those extra elements.

However, since the question was on styling list with inline elements, here's a dabblet to do this: http://dabblet.com/gist/3172553
The css could be nicer for modern browsers but since IE8 (and maybe IE7) are a requirement, I left out the `nth-child` selectors and used a separate class for the first and last element to add extra styling.

```
#nav_list, nav {
    display: block;
}

#nav_list li {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin-right: -1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav_list li.last {
    margin: 0;
}
```

Don't forget, if you use inline elements, line breaks count as spaces and will be displayed. So your html for the list needs to be all in one line:

```
<nav>
  <ul id="nav_list">
    <li id="home" class="first">Home</li><li id="shop"> Shop</li><li id="game">Game</li><li id="map">Map</li><li id="info" class="last">Information</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: yep, as I said, there are many solutions for the same thing, but I usually tend to prefer a clean an organized HTML. Using all those li elements in one line of code is a little bit ugly and hard to read. Well, it's just a question of preference I think =)

Comment: I'd prefer clean html and `display: box;` myself` ;) However, regarding the `inline-block` positioning problem of the op, you have to have the li's on a single line or you'll get ugly spaces in between.

Comment: You probably can solve the ugly spaces with negative margins. And I also prefer `display: block;`